# Worldizing (background noise, TV on a film.)

Tags: sound-design, television, backgroundambience, worldizing

I am totally clueless.
We made ​​a film, which takes place in a waste bag, I mean, it gives the feeling of the picture. A total, where a guy lying on a bed about 3m away from the camera, surrounded by black bag is paved with the environment. it looks good.:)

I recorded the atmosphere with Neumann M-S michrophone on the shooting. The actor is lying on the left and eating potato chips, he moved on the bag and it rattle. The right side of the bed a TV screen is flashing with no sound, you can not see the contents)

So we have an atmosphere, the sound field, and i have to put in the TV sound. Not facing the viewer, 3m from us, and the best fit to the recorded atmosphere.

I have used, eq, speakerphone, altiverb, but I could not reach the effect, no matter how twisted the parameters. I know that there are no rules, but I really hope that you can say something sensible, especially since I started out by many.

The sound is dropped from the picture, it is very difficult ..:)

I can write many things, but I think to begin to talk about it, and asked if perhaps, answer, or when you need i can place a link here from the short part from the movie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you need to fit the television sound in with the location recordings? Have you tried [worldizing](http://filmsound.org/terminology/worldizing.htm) it? Recording it through a television with the same Neumann should help. Perhaps go back to the same space where you shot the scene and record it there. Be sure to do several recordings from different distances if you get the opportunity.

Comment: yes exactly, worldizing!
but many times, u could not record everything on the field (for example, the director has not yet decided exactly what will be come from the tv), and u cant go back.
In this case, what's the solution?

Comment: Yes, you can't always go back. But that's not to say that the room you shot in will be best for worldizing the sound, you always have creative license over accuracy. It also depends on how dry your dialog track is. It's much easier to make everything sit in the mix if it's a good clean recording in an unreverberant space, you can then treat everything with a bit of the same reverb and it all holds together. If it's a low budget short or similar I often quiz the director on the locations.. background noise, damping etc. Inexperienced directors often plan their locations on look alone.

Comment: on this film we have not dialog, we have just atmo(bag rattleing, body moveing), and 3m from the actor in a small place its not dry of course. :(

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you worldize all the sounds and not just the TV sound? When a sound I want seems out of place, I've added it to all the sounds that I wanted to worldize and it usually works out. If it doesn't sound right the first time, put the recorded track through again. Each time you worldize, you record fresh ambience, and that will help the sound effects become more realistic. Have a look at [this](http://takuyakatsu.wordpress.com/2009/09/16/presence/) for a clearer idea of what I'm explaining. It's a technique I've used a far bit over the years to good effect.

Comment: I also remembered it, but it is very difficult to re-add the bag rustling, eating, because we have very short time to make it. but next time, im not use stereo or JUST stereo for moveing, eating, steps, etc.. i try to record it dry as i can, and after i can worldizing everything. . . .....if that really is the best way

Comment: unfortunately the soundcloud tracks not working on your link:(

Comment: but it looks very intresting

Comment: @bohitomi I've updated the link, you can have a listen now.

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess, but can you take an impulse response of the room in question, then pass your audio through Altiverb (using that impulse response), through a very good monitor speaker, and then back into your Neumann at the 3m distance?  That would seem to get you pretty close (at least in my head.)

Comment: it looks good idea next time, but i cant go back now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to manipulate the TV sound in mono?

Comment: it was a mono track, but i make a stereo, and after i put the plug in there

Comment: I was wondering if you kept it on mono (older TV's are mono and it may sound more cinematic/match the image), some hard EQ and the reverb (keeping the pre-delay to the minimum, as the Tv is close to the wall..) I'm talking all theory but I did something similar with a radio and it didn't work bad :)